# Error al insertar datos en un formulario con php

Tags: php, mysqli, post, undefined

Estoy intentando insertar datos en esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy utilizando es éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que me da este error:

**Notice: Undefined Index: Peso In /Storage/Ssd5/504/12005504/Public_html/Hojadegastos/Html/Peso.Php On Line 37.**

El archivo conexion.php funciona bien, al hacerle un *echo* me indica que la conexión está establecida, y la línea 37 del error es la línea 
**$peso = trim ($_POST['Peso']);**

Por favor, ¿alguien me puede indicar el error? Además es un error bastante recurrente que me sucede a menudo.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Eso es porque no existe el indice "Peso" en $_POST, comprueba que en tu formulario el campo se llame y tenga el name "Peso" exactamente.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error es el siguiente: no tienes un elemento de tu formulario cuyo nombre (name) sea "Peso". Seguramente si ejecutas un `dump($_post)` no te lo va a traer.
O puede que se este mandando con otro con otro name, por un error de tipeo.

Revisa tu formulario, deberias tener algo del estilo:

```
<form action="NOMBRE_TU_ARCHIVO_PHP.php" method="post">
  <p>Peso: <input type="text" name="Peso" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

La propiedad como se ve en el ejemplo, el name="Peso" indica que se va a mandar por Post (por el method) a tu archivo .php (action).
Espero que te sea util, saludos!!!

**EDIT**
Sobre lo que comentas *De hecho, al cargar la página sale dicho error, pero si mandas los datos a la BD lo borra, y si vuelves a introducir nuevos datos no aparece. Solo aparece cuando se carga la página –*

Deberias comprobar con empty 
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php
Para comprobar si existe ese indice y no es vacio en la variable $_post, como 
Tipo

```
if(!empty($_post['peso']) { 
   $peso = $_post['peso'] 
   // el resto del code que copiaste,
   // haces el insert
   // obtenes el resutl de tu consulta
   // de esta forma te evitas: problema del indice no definido y 
   // podes hacer el insert con el dato que viene del form
}
```

Cuando carga el archivo, debe intentar acceder a ese indice en tu variable $_post. Al no estar definido, hasta el momento de hacer el submit del formulario, te da ese error.

Comment: Pues efectivamente, he corregido el nombre en el campo name y ahora me guarda el dato en la base de datos. Lo que pasa es que cuando entro en la página en cuestión me aparece el error **Notice: Undefined Index: Peso In /Storage/Ssd5/504/12005504/Public_html/Hojadegastos/Html/Peso.Php On Line 37,** pero como digo luego funciona bien

Comment: De hecho, al cargar la página sale dicho error, pero si mandas los datos a la BD lo borra, y si vuelves a introducir nuevos datos no aparece. Solo aparece cuando se carga la página

Comment: Te agregue un comentario, fijate si no es eso

Comment: Muchas gracias Cristian. Lo que no entiendo es que al introducir el isset, me indica que la variable no está definida en la línea en la que se ejecuta la consulta, pero la ingesta de datos en la base de datos funciona. ¿Es entonces solo una cuestión de formato?

Comment: Ahora te edite la respuesta, capa que no me exprese bien

Comment: Avisame si te funciona y si esta resuelto, marcala como resulta

Comment: En este caso en concreto, yo utilizaría !empty. Lo que te interesa es que la variable de peso este definida y tenga un valor. Si solo haces un isset podría darse el caso de entrar con un null o con una cadena de caracteres, por ej.

Comment: Tanto con empty como con isset me está dando el mismo error:  **Undefined Variable: Peso** en linea 38, que es *$consulta = "INSERT INTO peso (Fecha, peso) VALUES (NOW(), '$peso')";*. Además, en la BD he cambiado el formato de peso y ahora el formato predeterminado es "0,0", para que no tenga un valor nulo. Muchas gracias a todos